# List of all available actions for Ad Report Stats - Facebook Ads Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

Where can I find a list of all the available action types for the Ad Report Stats (such as video_p50_watched_actions)

[Ad Report Stats Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adreportstats/)

ad report stats usage example: 
`act_XXXX/reportstats?actions_group_by=['action_type']&date_preset=last_7_days&filters=[{'field':'campaign_id','type':'in','value':[]}]&data_columns=['campaign_name','video_p50_watched_actions']&access_token=ZZZ`